# Boolean Simplification - Q=A.B.(~B+C)+B.C+B

Tags: boolean-expression, booleanquery

I've been struggling with boolean simplification in class, and took it to practice some more at home. I found a list of questions, but they don't have any answers or workings. This one I'm stuck on, if you could answer clearly showing each step I'd much appreciate:

**Q=A.B.(~B+C)+B.C+B**

I tried looking for a calculator to give me the answer and then to work out how to get to that, but I'm lost

(I'm new to this)

Edit: ~B = NOT B

Comment: Is ~B supposed to be B'?

Comment: @AdiC you mean ¬B, right?

Comment: @Lovis No... it's showing a tilda for me.

Comment: @AdiC I meant instead of B' - but what I actually wanted to say is, that the whole equation is somehow ambiguous. sorry, joking attempt failed

Comment: @Lovis Oh :) I've never done this so I wouldn't have understood :)

Comment: ~B = NOT B, Sorry if that's not what you're used to

Comment: @J.McGill It's fine :) It's just that all the online sites I've found use B' so I assumed that's what you meant.

Comment: @AdiC I've seen that too, just the most recent one I saw was that format so I put that

Comment: Since I've never done this, I have a question. Is there any boolean algebraic equation linking `A`, `B`, and `C`? Maybe something like `A = B + C`? Or are they completely independent of each other?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Let's be lazy and use [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html#simplification-and-equivalence-testing), a Python library for symbolic computation.

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.logic import simplify_logic
>>> a, b, c = symbols('a, b, c')
>>> expr = a & b & (~b | c) | b & c | b # A.B.(~B+C)+B.C+B
>>> simplify_logic(expr)
b
```

There are two ways to go about such a formula:

- Applying simplifications,
- Brute force

Let's look at brute force first. The following is a dense truth table (for a better looking table, look at [Wα](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+%26+b+%26+(~b+%7C+c)+%7C+b+%26+c+%7C+b)), enumerating all possible value for a, b and c, alongside the values of the expression.

```
a b c -- a & b & (~b | c) | b & c | b = Q
0 0 0    0   0    10 1 0    0 0 0   0 = 0
0 0 1    0   0    10 1 1    0 0 1   0 = 0
0 1 0    0   1    01 0 0    1 0 0   1 = 1
0 1 1    0   1    01 1 1    1 1 1   1 = 1
1 0 0    1   0    10 1 0    0 0 0   0 = 0
1 0 1    1   0    10 1 1    0 0 1   0 = 0
1 1 0    1   1    01 1 0    1 0 0   1 = 1
1 1 1    1   1    01 1 1    1 1 1   1 = 1
```

You can also think of the expression as a tree, which will depend on the precedence rules (e.g. usually *AND* binds stronger than *OR*, see also [this question on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128504/boolean-algebra-operation-precedence)).

So the expression:

```
a & b & (~b | c) | b & c | b
```

is a [disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) of three terms:

```
a & b & (~b | c)
b & c
b
```

You can try to reason about the individual terms, knowing that only one has to be true (as this is a disjunction).

The last two will be true, if and only if b is true. For the first, this a bit harder to see, but if you look closely: you have now a [conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) (terms concatenated by *AND*): All of them must be true, for the whole expression to be true, so a and b must be true. Especially *b* must be true.

In summary: For the whole expression to be true, in all three top-level cases, b must be true (and it will be false, if b is false). So it simplifies to just b.

Explore more on Wolfram Alpha:

- https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+%26+b+%26+(~b+%7C+c)+%7C+b+%26+c+%7C+b

[image]

Comment: It's good and all to have the answer, but I won't exactly be having a python program in my exam to use. Really I need to understand how to get the answer as well

Comment: @J.McGill, *if in doubt, use brute force*. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this, so I'm using [this site](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~ghosh/9-26-13.pdf) to help me.

`A.B.(B' + C) = A.(B.B' + B.C) = A.(0 + B.C) = A.(B.C)`

So the expression is now `A.(B.C) + B.C + B`.

Not sure about this, but I'm guessing `A.(B.C) + (B.C) = (A + 1).(B.C)`.
This equals `A.(B.C)`.

So the expression is now `A.(B.C) + B`.

As `A.(B + C) = B.(A.C)`, the expression is now `B.(A.C) + B`, which equals `(B + 1).(A.C) = B.(A.C)`.

NOTE: This isn't complete yet, so please avoid downvoting as I'm not finished yet (posted this to help the OP understand the first part).

Answer (score 0):

```
A.B.(~B+C) + B.C + B = A.B.~B + A.B.C + B.C + B    ; Distribution
                     = A.B.C + B.C + B             ; Because B.~B = 0
                     = B.C + B                     ; Because A.B.C <= B.C
                     = B                           ; Because B.C <= B
```